# Is there a faster way to insert -data from random indices in 1d array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 1D array where I remove all NaN to do some post processing. While doing this, I keep a track of indices where NaNs were (so that I can re-build this 1D array for further analysis). After processing the data when I insert back the NaNs/0s into these indices using np.insert and for loop, it takes 6 min to do that. Is there a better way to perform this?

code:

#%%  track of removed indices, zf is the 1D array I am processing

```
inds, z_wo_nan = [],[]     
for i, ele in enumerate(zf):
    if np.isnan(ele) == True:
        inds.append(i)
        z_wo_nan.append(ele)
```

#%%  inds will be used to re-build zf
#%%  ------post processing------

```
zphas_f = np.delete(zf, inds)
xf_f = np.delete(xf, inds)
yf_f =np.delete(yf, inds)
    
 
xy_f = np.concatenate((xf_f[None,:],yf_f[None,:], np.ones(xf_f.shape)[None,:]), axis=0  ).transpose()
xy_inv_f = np.linalg.pinv(xy_f)   
abc_f = np.matmul(xy_inv_f, zphas_f[:,None] )      
rem_plane = np.matmul(xy_f, abc_f)   
z_dd = zphas_f - rem_plane.transpose()[0]

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(xf_f,yf_f,c=zphas_f)    #2 with values, no 0 or nan

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(xf_f,yf_f,c=rem_plane.transpose()[0])    #2 with values, no 0 or nan


plt.figure()
plt.scatter(xf_f,yf_f,c=z_dd)    #2 with values, no 0 or nan
```

#%% post processing finished-------------------
#%% inserting back removed indices - inserting 0 instead of nan

```
idx_del = inds
val_del = 0

z_dd_f_rec = z_dd

for i in idx_del:
    z_dd_f_rec = np.insert(z_dd_f_rec,i,0)   # 6 min for processing!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Solution as suggested:

#%%  track of removed indices

```
inds = np.where(np.isnan(zf))[0] # Finds all indices where there is NaN
indsf = np.where(~np.isnan(zf))[0] # Finds all indices where there is NaN
```

#%% post processing- rebuilding from new array

```
z_demo = np.empty(np.shape(zf))
for i in inds:
    z_demo[i] = 0
      
for i,j in enumerate(indsf):
    z_demo[j] = z_dd_f_rec[i]
```

Comment: the problem is that you're using a O(n^2), because you insert elements one by one and it costs you a lot, while you can use a O(n) operation : rebuilding the list from an empty one. It should be faster, tell me if it so :)

Comment: Thank you, your idea of re-building from empty list works. Thank you :) Also I reduced my lines of code as suggested by @Deloo. I include the suggestions in my question

Comment: glad to have helped you!

Answer (score 0):

1. `== True` is useless
2. Numpy has functions to do almost everything efficiently. See this example:

```py
nan_indexes = np.where(np.isnan(zf))[0] # Finds all indices where there is NaN
zf_without_nan = zf[np.invert(np.isnan(zf))] # Takes only element that are not NaN
```

3. You don't need to recreate zf because the functions above don't modify its content but they create new arrays.
4. Given point 3. you don't need `nan_indexes` from point 2. anymore since zf is unmodified.
5. Each line of 2. takes milliseconds even with an array of 3 million numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but in the post processing part I modify the values of zf_without_nan. And I want to use these new values of zf_without_nan, but I also want to re-build back to the form of zf. In this case, I have to use np.insert and for loop, and I need to do it in a better way.